# Store specialised types in a vector

Tags: c++, templates

-Essentially, I have a template class, called `Foo` which holds a variant. I want to have a setter function within `Foo` which assigns the variant to the template type of `Foo` (of course in this trivial demonstration we assume that the user chooses a `T` for `Foo<T>` which exists in the variant.

-How am I able to store these objects contiguously? It would be useful for me, since I may need to iterate over all of instantiated `Foo`'s.

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
    using Attribute = std::variant<std::string, int>;
private:
    Attribute attribute;
public:
    const Attribute& GetAttribute() const noexcept { return attribute; }
    void SetAttribute(T&& inp) { attribute = std::forward<T>(inp); }
};

class Bar
{
private:
    //Store a vector of `Foo<T>` here.
    
public:

};
```

Comment: You can store a vector of `Foo<T>` where `T` is one type easily. You can't store `Foo<T>`  where `T` can be multiple types into one vector in this way. That's not how templates work.

Comment: Does `Foo` need to be a template? Can't you just make `SetAttribute` templated?

Answer (score 2):

`Foo` needs not to be template, because it doesn't actually use `T`. The only use of `T` is in `Foo::SetAttribute`, so you can make just this method as template:

```
class Foo
{
    using Attribute = std::variant<std::string, int>;
private:
    Attribute attribute;
public:
    const Attribute& GetAttribute() const noexcept { return attribute; }
    template<typename T>
    void SetAttribute(T&& inp) { attribute = std::forward<T>(inp); }
};
```

Then you can create a vector of `Foo` without problem:

```
class Bar
{
private:
    std::vector<Foo> fooVect;
    
public:

};
```

Comment: But Foo is exposed to the user. The user will be responsible for setting the state of the variable through this setter function. Would this be bad design as they can practically use any templated type when setting?

Comment: @jasbindra00 Compiler will not allow to use a type that is not `std::string` or `int` (or convertible to either), but [the error message is somewhat cryptic](https://godbolt.org/z/ac4r5a). If you prefer, you may do two public overloads instead of a template, this way you will be explicit about what types are accepted.